# Web.config equivalent to “using static MyClass;” in <add namespace=“MyClass” />

Tags: razor, web-config, static-classes

In ASP.Net, you can add a namespace to all Razor views by adding the following code to the View folder’s Web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace=“MyClass” />
    </namespaces>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

This is equivalent to putting the statement “using MyClass;” at the top of a C# file.

However, how would I add a namespace to Web.config as a “static” class, where I can access the class’s methods directly within views without having to write out “MyClass.MyMethod();” for example?

You can already do this by putting the statement “using static MyClass;” at the top of a C# file (C# 6 is required, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just appends whatever it is you put as namespace. Just needs to append the `static` keyword to the namespace.

So as you pointed out `<add namespace=“MyClass” />` is equivalent to `using MyClass;`

Change to `<add namespace=“static MyClass” />`, which is equivalent to `using static MyClass;`

In your case:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace=“static MyClass” />
    </namespaces>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

should be what you're looking for